# Json file within a dependency could not be found

Tags: java, json, javafx, path

So, I wrote my own backend and transformed it into an artifact (dependency). The dependecy contains three .json files. It's directory tree is the following:

```
/resources/
/com/
/META-INF/
```

Now, when I'm trying to add the dependency as a library to another project (to access methods etc.) this message is being thrown:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Yasin\Desktop\LeagueLookup\data\deps\resources\masteries.json (The system can not find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
```

This is the code within the dependency:

```
public static String PROJECT_ROOT_DIR = new File(Config.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParent();

public static String RESOURCES = PROJECT_ROOT_DIR + "/resources/";

public static File MASTERIES = new File(RESOURCES + "masteries.json");
```

This is the outcome when I Sysout the PROJECT_ROOT_DIR path within the dependency

```
C:\Users\Yasin\Desktop\Riot-API\out\production
```

Everything works perfectly fine when I create a class in the Backend and run code on it, but everything messes up when I try to use that dependency for another project.

I also had it working with it's real path

it looked like this:

```
C:\Users\Yasin\Desktop\LeagueLookup\data\deps\main.jar\resources\masteries.json
```

but that didn't work aswell (I read somewhere to use an InputStream, tried that, but it always gave me null although the pathing was perfectly fine)
My goal:
I want to make the API use it's own data, I do not want to grab data from another source but my own source.

Hope you can help me

Comment: Can no one help me with this ?

Comment: It sometimes takes time for others to understand your problem ;) and we dont get paid for our help

Comment: Yeah I forget that xD Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have misunderstood how the java-applications are constructed.

Writing java-applications (mostly) results in having JAR-files, which are executed anywhere. If you require to have access to some file stored inside your generated JAR-file (please use something like maven or gradle), you can have some InputStream. Your handling via `Config.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()` is just wrong, because that information about the sourcecode might be removed from the compiled `.class`-file, and especially will be different when sharing/shipping your application.

For having some InputStream of some stored file inside your jar-file, you have use this:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/masteries.json")
```

As "resources" is no default-structure of inside the jar, you might need to double-check what is inside your jar-file.

Comment: This is what I needed. And I kinda understood it the whole time, I think I just used the wrong classloader (seems like ClassLoader#getSystemClassLoader somehow supports searching for resources in the root directory). So the mistake I did in other attempts was using the wrong class. Thank you so much kind sir.

Comment: When using `Config.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("masteries.json")` the file is expected in the same package as the Config-class. I often forget about this myself ;)

Comment: I kinda knew it, but I didn't know how I'd edit the path so that it's leading to the root directory within the jar. Thank you anyways!!!!